# check if the div id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have project that concerns about calendars, at first i have 1 calendar and now i want to have another one but they have different values.

```
<div id="cal">
....
</div>
<div id="calq">
....
</div>
```

my question is, how can I check if `div` id is "calq" in javascript?

if div.id == "calq" ?

...
at first i have ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    monthYear = Date.today();
    var cal = new Calendar();
    cal.generateHTML();
    $('#cal').html(cal.getHTML());
    setMonthPrice();
    setSpecialPrice()
</script>
```

then i added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    monthYear = Date.today();
    var calq = new Calendar();
    calq.generateHTML();
    $('#calq').html(calq.getHTML());
    setMonthQuantity();
    setSpecialQuantity();
</script>
```

but the `setMonthQuantity()` also called by `cal`, i just want the `setMonthQuantity()` only for `calq`

```
function setMonthQuantity()
{
    var weekdayBaseQuantity;
    weekdayBaseQuantity = {{ product.quantity }};

    $('td.calendar-day').append('<div class="dayquantity">' + weekdayBaseQuantity + '</div>');
    $('td.Sat .dayquantity, td.Sun .dayquantity').text( weekdayBaseQuantity );
}
```

Comment: Add some more info about the javascript you are using, is this part of a foreach loop? Are you using jQuery to get all your divs?

Comment: Can you please show your `setMonthQuantity()` function too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To determine the existence, in clean javascript

```
if(document.getElementById("calq")!='undefined')
{
    // do something, it exists 
}
```

using jquery

```
if($("#calq").length)
{
    // do something, it exists 
}
```

To check the id, in clean javascript

```
if(this.getAttribute('id')=="calc")
{
    // do something, it exists 
}
```

Using jquery

```
if($(this).attr("id")=="calq")
{
    // do something, it exists 
}
```

Comment: thanks Heera your code helps me, i choose this : `if($("#calq").length)`

Comment: Welcome, this will work with jquery, hope you know that better than me.

Comment: `this.id` will work just as well as `this.getAttribute('id')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do check it, for example, via Jquery. I suppose that you want to make something like `switch` and for each div do some operation. If I'm right you can use Jquery's `each` function for looping against div elements and following condition for checking id's.

```
if($(this).attr("id")=="calq")
```

Comment: this.id works fine as well, always faster to use pure js where possible :)

Comment: Yes, but @gadss doesn't give a lot information about what he wants to do. So, I wrote more general usage.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
if (​$('#calq').length === 1) {
 // there is id = calq
}​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the best solution would be to pass in the div to the functions you are calling. That way you know the div you are dealing with.
eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    monthYear = Date.today();
    var cal = new Calendar();
    cal.generateHTML();
    var calDiv = $('#cal');
    calDiv.html(cal.getHTML());
    setMonthPrice(calDiv);
    setSpecialPrice(calDiv)
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    monthYear = Date.today();
    var calq = new Calendar();
    var calqDiv = $('#cal');
    calqDiv.html(cal.getHTML());
    setMonthQuantity(calqDiv);
    setSpecialQuantity(calqDiv);
</script>
```

I am assuming the `$('td.calendar-day')` is in the calendar HTML? If so setMonthQuantity would be something like

```
function setMonthQuantity(calDiv)
{
    var weekdayBaseQuantity;
    weekdayBaseQuantity = {{ product.quantity }};

    calDiv.closest('td.calendar-day').append('<div class="dayquantity">' + weekdayBaseQuantity + '</div>');
    calDiv.closest('td.Sat .dayquantity, td.Sun .dayquantity').text( weekdayBaseQuantity );
}
```

Comment: not sure about the closest call there, found it with 2 seconds of googling